# Запретить горизонтальный scroll на мобильных устройствах

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Мне нужно запретить горизонтальный `scroll` на мобильных устройствах, особенно на iOS, так как на Android `overflow` работает правильно.

Сейчас имею такое содержание `css`:

```
html, body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

В `head` прописано:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
```

Нужно запретить именно для body, а не для отдельного элемента.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
html, body {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```